# Immortal Soldier - Cured with Honey based salve, wounds heal, fears drowning?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember that title of a 1960's short story about a soldier in medieval times who is treated on the field of battle by a physician using a salve made in part from honey.  The soldier heals and discovers that no matter how badly he is wounded he always heals. Hundreds of years later the soldier is still searching to complete the physician's original mixture. He fears being drowned.

Comment: Sounds like a rejected draft to Highlander 2 :)

Comment: @DVK, no, because MacLeod doesn't fear drowning. :)

Comment: @cjm - you should re-watch the Sean Connery training montage in the boat from HL1

Answer (score 10):

This is [“Whatever Happened To Corporal Cuckoo?”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57439) by [Gerald Kersh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Kersh). It's been anthologised often and you should be able to find a copy easily.