# An immortal soldier story

Tags: story-identification, immortality

Looking for a story I read back in the late 60s, it starts on a troop ship returning to the US post-1945. The two characters are discussing the war and one shares a secret, he cannot die. He was born in the middle ages and was injured on a medieval battle field where a monk healed him and since then he has not died.

Comment: Probably not the Casca series, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casca_%28series%29. Casca's nature is discovered in a battlefield hospital in Vietnam, and he was cursed by Jesus on the cross. That's three marks of not matching.

Comment: @Larry: I know this story, though I can't *quite* place it. I know it's a short story though, and fairly old. There's a line where the immortal soldier is showing his scars and says something like "...this is all I got in this one..." showing a line of bullet scars across his throat. Maybe Sturgeon or Bradbury?

Comment: Yep It sounds right.

Comment: Re-opened. The OP of the [supposed dupe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22942/immortal-soldier-cured-with-honey-based-salve-wounds-heals-fears-drowning?noredirect=1&lq=1) hasn't accepted (or confirmed) that it's the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's "Whatever Happened to Corporal Cuckoo?" by Gerald Kersh, which is included in the anthology [*Nightshade and Damnations*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1939140153) .

Here's a couple of edited excerpts:

> The Cunard White Star liner the Queen Mary sailed from Greenock, at
>   the mouth of the river Clyde, on July 6th, 1945, bound for New York,
>   packed tight with passengers... I bring all this back into memory to
>   prove that I was there, as a war correspondent, on my way to the
>   Pacific... But in the excitement of that tremendous moment, when
>   thousands of men were struggling and jostling, laughing and crying,
>   and snapping cameras at the New York skyline which is the most
>   beautiful in the world, I lost Corporal Cuckoo. I have made exhaustive
>   enquiries as to his whereabouts, but that extraordinary man had
>   disappeared like a puff of smoke...

and:

> He was a light-haired man of
>   medium height, but he must have weighed at least a hundred and ninety
>   pounds, for he was ponderously built, and had enormously heavy
>   bones... but no one who saw Corporal Cuckoo could fail to remember his
>   scars. There was a frightful indentation in his skull, between his
>   left eyebrow and his right ear. When I first noticed him, I remembered
>   an axe murder at which I shuddered many years ago when I was a crime
>   reporter. “He must have an extraordinary constitution if he lives to
>   walk around with a scar like that,” I thought. His chin and throat
>   were puckered scar tissue such as marks the place where flesh has been
>   badly burned and well healed. Half of his right ear was missing and
>   close by there was another scar, from cheekbone to mastoid. The back
>   of his right hand appeared to have been hacked with a knife—I counted
>   at least four formidable cuts, all old and white and deep. He conveyed
>   this impression: that a long time ago, a number of people had got
>   together to butcher him with hatchets, sabres, and knives, and that,
>   in spite of their most determined efforts, he had survived. For all
>   his scars were old. Yet the man was young—not more than thirty-five as
>   I guessed.

and:

> I said: “That was a nasty one you got, up there.”
>   “What? This?” he
>   said, carelessly striking the scar with the flat of a hard hand.
>   “This? Nasty one? I’ll say it was a nasty one. Why, some of my brains
>   came out. And look here—” He unbuttoned his shirt and pulled up his
>   singlet with his left hand, while he opened and lit a battered Zippo
>   with his right. “Take a look at that.”
>  I cried out in
>   astonishment. I had never seen a living body so incredibly mauled and
>   mutilated. In the vacillating light of the flame I saw black shadows
>   bobbing and weaving in a sort of blasted wilderness of crags, chasms,
>   canyons, and pits. His torso was like a place laid waste by the wrath
>   of God—burst asunder from below, scorched from above, shattered by
>   thunderbolts, crushed by landslides, ravaged by hurricanes... “Good
>   God, man, you must have been torn in two and put together again!” I
>   said. Corporal Cuckoo merely laughed, and held his lighter so that I
>   could see his body from stomach to hips. Between the strong muscles,
>   just under the liver, there was an old scar into which, old and healed
>   as it was, you might have laid three fingers. Cutting across this,
>   another scar, more than half as deep but more than twelve inches long,
>   curved away downwards towards the groin on the left. Another appalling
>   scar came up from somewhere below the buckle of his belt and ended in
>   a deep triangular hole in the region of the diaphragm. And there were
>   other scars—but the lighter went out, and Corporal Cuckoo buttoned up
>   his shirt... “Tell me,” I said, “how the devil did you come by all
>   that? They’re old scars. You couldn’t have got them in this war—”
>   He slid down the knot of his tie, unbuttoned his collar, pulled his
>   shirt aside, and said, dispassionately: “No. Look—this is all I got
>   this time.” He pointed nonchalantly to his throat. I counted five
>   bullet scars in a cluster, spaced like fingertips of a half-opened
>   hand, at the base of the throat. “Light machine-gun,” he said.
>   “But this is impossible!” I said, while he readjusted his tie. “That
>   little packet there must have cut one or two big arteries and smashed
>   your spine to smithereens.”
>  “Sure it did,” said Corporal
>   Cuckoo.
>  “And how old did you say you were?” I asked.
>  Corporal
>   Cuckoo replied: “Round about four hundred and thirty-eight.”
>   “Thirty-eight?”
>  “I said, four hundred and thirty-eight.”
>  The
>   man is mad, I thought. “Born 1907?” I asked.
>  “1507,” said Corporal
>   Cuckoo, fingering the dent in his skull.

And the "monk":

> “Well,” said Corporal Cuckoo, with scorn. “You don’t even know the
>   meaning of what you were reading in your little book—Pipeur ou
>   hasardeur de dez, and all that—even when it’s put down in cold print.
>   I’ll put it so that you’ll understand. The doctor said something like
>   this: ‘Come here and look, sir, come and see! This fellow’s brains
>   were bursting out of his head. If I had applied theriac, he would be
>   buried and forgotten by now. Instead, having no theriac, for want of
>   something better, I applied my digestive. And see what has happened.
>   His eyes have opened! Observe, also, that the bones are creeping
>   together, and over this beating brain a sort of skin is forming. My
>   treatment must be right, because God is healing him!’
>  “After I
>   blinked my eyes, I couldn’t open them again. I couldn’t see. But I
>   could still hear, and when I heard that I was as scared as hell they
>   were going to bury me alive. And I couldn’t move. But the doctor I’d
>   seen said: ‘After five days this poor soldier’s flesh is still sweet,
>   and, weary as I am, I have my wits about me, and I swear to you that I
>   saw his eyes open.’ Then he called out: ‘Jehan! Bring the
>   digestive!. . . By your leave, sir, I will keep this man, until he
>   comes back to life, or begins to stink. And into this wound I am going
>   to pour some more of my digestive.’
>  “Then I felt something running
>   into my head. It hurt like hell. It was like ice water dripped into
>   your brains. I thought This is it!—and then I went numb all over, and
>   then I went dead again, until I woke up later in another place.

Comment: Yes Spot on, many thanks indeed.

Comment: just went on line and bought it again. Once again, many thanks for the responses.

Comment: @Larry: My pleasure. If it allows you, please click on the "Accepted" checkmark to close your question. Thanks!