# Soldier becomes immortal due to honey formula

Tags: story-identification, immortality

I'm looking for a short story about a soldier who runs into another soldier (on a troop ship during WWII I think).

The soldier tells his comrade a fantastic story of how he was fighting in a Napoleonic War(?) and was struck with an axe in the head. He was treated with some stuff made with honey, among other ingredients.

He became immortal and was tying to recreate the formula.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Immortal Soldier - Cured with Honey based salve, wounds heals, fears drowning?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22942/immortal-soldier-cured-with-honey-based-salve-wounds-heals-fears-drowning)

Comment: Related, not dupe; [SF collection: house slips through 4 dimensions in earthquake, person becomes immortal during Napoleonic wars](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90499/sf-collection-house-slips-through-4-dimensions-in-earthquake-person-becomes-im?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Definitely Corporal Cuckoo and therefore a dupe.  But the answer to the other question is not accepted.  *sigh*.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Tell me about it.

Comment: Possible dupe of [An immortal soldier story](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82386/an-immortal-soldier-story?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

This is almost certainly "[Whatever Happened to Corporal Cuckoo](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57439)"  by Gerald Kersh.

This story has been asked about many times and answered correctly each time, but apparently no one wants to formally accept an answer on it:

- [Immortal Soldier - Cured with Honey based salve, wounds heal, fears drowning?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22942/immortal-soldier-cured-with-honey-based-salve-wounds-heal-fears-drowning/26398#26398)
  (no accepted answer)
- [Does Anyone Know the Whereabouts of Private Coo-coo?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151043/does-anyone-know-the-whereabouts-of-private-coo-coo/151052#151052)
  (no accepted answer)
- [An immortal soldier story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82386/an-immortal-soldier-story/82388#82388)
  (answer accepted in comment)

Also asked about in this question [SF collection: house slips through 4 dimensions in earthquake, person becomes immortal during Napoleonic wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90499/sf-collection-house-slips-through-4-dimensions-in-earthquake-person-becomes-im/90501#90501) which was looking for an anthology ID, not a story ID.